# Word to describe someone picking up on accent/dialect quickly and easily. And without trying?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have recently moved down to Alabama with my fiance. And I have, without even my noticing, heavily picked up on the drawl down here without any sort of trying involved. A good phrase or word would be appreciated.

However, I understand this is a moderately loaded concept. I would love any help, direction, or advice on how to say this better, if not an appropriate word or phrase.

Comment: or perhaps: sponge-like?

Comment: It's not a single word, but you have "an ear for accents" or "an ear for language".

Comment: @JohnFeltz To me, that sounds like someone who can easily distinguish two similar accents or languages -- e.g. telling apart an Alabama and Georgian accent easily -- rather than someone who acquires them quickly.

Comment: Could you give us an example sentence in which your word/phrase would fit?

Comment: Twangsigent, maybe. (I'm amazed that *twangslate* isn't in Urban)

Comment: Well bless your heart, you're finally learning to speak properly. You're *immersed* now, you'll find yourself ordering sweet tea when you visit "the North". Do not do this. They do not understand tea.

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps a **natural mimic** with **a knack for absorbing an accent**?

That second phrase is used in a Quora answer:
   [How can some people catch the accent of a language so fast and speak it much like locals? What ability do they have?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-some-people-catch-the-accent-of-a-language-so-fast-and-speak-it-much-like-locals-What-ability-do-they-have/answer/Anne-W-Zahra?srid=JOFA)